# Does Express.js http response returns a promise by default

Tags: node.js, express, http

For instance, does `res.send(user)` in the below code returns a promise?

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)

    user.save().then(() => {
        res.send(user)
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to return a promise, you should use asynchronous functions instead of synchronous functions. Promises have been part of the language for years (standardized and introduced in ES2015), and have recently become more integrated, with async and await in ES2017.

```
app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
   try{
       const user = new User(req.body);
       await user.save();
       res.send(user);
   } catch(e){
       res.status(400).send(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need await to req.body ```const user = new User( req.body)```

Comment: If you use async-await you don't need to call then. `await user.save()` and a line below `res.send(user)`

Comment: @Abjullah the async-await in the callback doesn’t effect the res.send method. If we were to return something from that function it would return a promise, but express doesn’t use it for the res.send anyhow. I still don't have an answer (I also assume that it doesn’t return a promise, but can't prove It at the moment), and you’re welcome to have another shot